# what is Create wallet using blockchain api (PHP)

Tags: blockchain, bitcoind, api, blockchain.info

Im wondering to know, what is use of **Create wallet programitically Block chain API**  [Block Chain api here](https://blockchain.info/api/create_wallet)

What it will provide?

Where can i get the api code? Any tutorials ?

Can i provide my website users to Create Block Chain wallet. And provide funds transfer?

Comment: do you have a link?

Comment: updated in my question

Comment: What exactly do you mean with api code? on the side there is an example on how to call the api.

Comment: what is the use of this api?

Answer (score 3):

This API allows you to create a new Wallet on Blockchain.info. It's the same as if you are registering on the webside but programmatically. On Blockchain.info you can do all thing either of the website or programmatically, which can be very usefull.

If you want to call the api from PHP, you need to send a JSON-Request to https://blockchain.info/api/v2/create_wallet. 
For a tutorial of JSON-Request in PHP look [here](http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/sending-json-data-remote-server/)

For sending and receiving Payments you need to use this api:
https://blockchain.info/api/blockchain_wallet_api
There are also some examples in PHP on this site.

Blockchain.info does not offer a referral programm, so there is no reward for providing new users.

Comment: I have already worked on sendmany block chain api which allow to send more than one address and succeeded in that. What i need to know , can i provide my website users to create their own wallet by using create_wallet?

Comment: yeah i guess thats something what this api is made for

Comment: i dont want to make any referral program, Im not getting why create_wallet programatically for?

Comment: its just a option you can use. there is no special cause they did this api.

Comment: i got that but for what purpose we can use?

Comment: i rly dont get what you want to hear?